# Split string into array and change the key name

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to split a string into an array where I can set the keyname instead of 1 2 3.

Here's the string:

```
"id=1&day=4&month=12&status=3"
```

The string can be just the ID, the ID and day, or all 4 together.

I want it to be like this:

```
array([id] => 1 [day] =>4...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`parse_str()`](https://php.net/parse_str):

```
parse_str("id=1&day=4&month=12&status=3", $parts);
var_export($parts);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/342819)